# How to make context variable dynamic in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to append 2 context variables together into a single context variable that is calculated at run-time?
For example: if I have  `{{contextA}}` (which equals 1) and `{{contextB}}` (which equals 'building') and I wanted to add these together to get context `{{1building}}` How would I do this?
I have tried:

`{{contextA + contextB}}`

`{{{{contextA}} + {{contextB}}}}`

`{{contextA |add: contextB}}`

`{{contextA contextB}}`

I suppose this is not possible and this needs to be done in the view using python, but it would be ideal if I could just combine context variables in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use `{% with` template tag as follows (docs here -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

```html
{% with newvar=contextA|add:contextB %}
    {{ newvar }}
{% endwith %}
```

`newvar` will have a new value if into a forloop where contextA or contextB change it's value.

As you want to show the value of a context variable with it's name equal to `newvar` value, the way to accomplish it is to create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) as follows:

```py
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def dynvarvalue(context, dynvarname):
    """ Returns the value of dynvarname into the context """
    return context.get(dynvarname, None)
```

I did a small proof of concept:

```
{% with 1building='1 building value' contextA='1' contextB='building' %}
  {% dynvarvalue contextA|add:contextB %}
{% endwith %}
```

Which produces the following output, which I think is what you are asking for:

```
1 building value
```

Hope this helps.

---

Note: take into account that if both variables can be transformed to an integer, they will not be concatenated and will be summed as docs says (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add)

Note2: I think there are some security caveats to take into account doing this.

Comment: Thanks @gabriel for the answer, but unfortunately this didn't work, the context in your example `{{ newvar }}` is rendered empty.

Comment: and which are the values for `contextA` and `contextB` variables? which is the output of `{{ contextA }}` and `{{ contextB }}`

Comment: The output of `{contextA}` is 1 and the output of `{contextB}` is 'building'. But I have another context I want called which is the combination of contextA and contextB which is `{ 1building }` so I was hoping by using what you suggested above it would combine contextA and contextB to call `{ 1building }`

Comment: Check my edits, you will need a custom template tag